# CPLEX: Variable lower bound in sum of objective function and constraints

Tags: c++, sum, set, cplex

I am currently trying to implement a objective function in CPLEX, which has a sum with a variable lower bound. It is:

```
sum(i in P)sum(k in W(i)).....
```

and so on...

The following shows the set W, which I want to import as an Excel file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIkrU.png)

So if i in the first sum is 1, then W(1) should be the set {15,19,20,19}.
If i in the first sum is 2, then W(2) should be th set {16,10,19} and so on..

Can anybody help me with the way of implementation so that it works?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
range P=1..2;

{int} W[P]=[{1,3},{10,100}];

int s=sum(i in P)sum(k in W[i]) k*i;

execute
{
  writeln(s);
}
```

gives

```
   224
```